# Can you switch off the schema check performed by ASPNET providers

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, sqlmembershipprovider

We have created a custom membership provider, but we have inherited the Role and Profile providers. The problem we are having is there appears to be calls being made to aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion by the providers - I assume its the Role or Profile provider as our membership provider isn't inherited and we don't call the db.

Is there a way to turn off this provider schema check other than write our own Role and Profile Providers.

I was hoping there was an attribute you can add/specify that does this.

Comment: If you have created a custom membership provider then you're the one doing the database code - or have you just inherited from the existing one and added your own bits?

Comment: I have added some more detail to the orginal question. Hopefully this answers what we are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We created our own Role and Profile providers but would welcome an alternative solution.